# Export DB query into Csv giving error on output

Tags: mysql

I am trying to export all the information regarding exam ie instructor, studentName, questions asked and response but it is giving me this error.[image]

i am using wampserver, and can i have two options at the same time ie export to Csv & Pdf or i can only configure 1 at a time?Please do assist. This is the code and database dump.

```
require_once '../connect.php';
require_once '../session.php';

// Check if the user is logged in
//if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    // Redirect or handle unauthorized access
  //  header('Location: ../login.php');
    //exit();
//}

// Set the content-type to CSV and specify the filename for download
header("Content-type: application/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=user_responses.csv");


// Get the user ID from the session
//$userID = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$examID = $_POST['examID'];
$userID = $_POST['userID'];

// Fetch user responses to questions
$sql = "SELECT q.question_text, qo.option_text, sr.chosen_option
        FROM user u
        INNER JOIN student_response sr ON u.user_id = sr.user_id
        INNER JOIN question q ON sr.question_id = q.question_id
        INNER JOIN question_option qo ON sr.option_id = qo.option_id
        WHERE u.user_id = $userID";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

// Create the output file (without saving it)
$dataFile = fopen('php://output', 'w');

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // Output the header
    fputcsv($dataFile, array("QUESTION", "OPTION", "CHOSEN OPTION"));

    // Output the data
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        fputcsv($dataFile, $row);
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

// Close the file handle
fclose($dataFile);

// Close the database connection
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

and this is the database dump :

### **-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.9.1
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/

-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Jan 22, 2020 at 05:22 PM
-- Server version: 10.4.8-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 7.3.11

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

### --
-- Database: `exam_portal`

---

### --
-- Table structure for table `assignment_status`

CREATE TABLE `assignment_status` (
`status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`value` varchar(45) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

### --
-- Dumping data for table `assignment_status`

INSERT INTO `assignment_status` (`status_id`, `value`) VALUES
(1, 'Awaiting approval'),
(2, 'Declined'),
(6, 'Graded'),
(4, 'In progress'),
(3, 'Ready'),
(5, 'Turned in');

---

### --
-- Table structure for table `course`

CREATE TABLE `course` (
`course_code` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
`course_name` varchar(256) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

### --
-- Dumping data for table `course`

INSERT INTO `course` (`course_code`, `course_name`) VALUES
('CSC307', 'Computer Architecture and Organization'),
('GST301', 'Entrepreneurial Studies II'),
('CSC334', 'Numerical Analysis'),
('CSC303', 'Object Oriented Programming'),
('CSC305', 'Operating Systems II'),
('CSC309', 'Sytem Analysis and Design'),
('CSC313', 'Web Programming');

---

### --
-- Table structure for table `exam`

CREATE TABLE `exam` (
`exam_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`instructor_id` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
`course_code` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
`title` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`no_of_questions` int(11) NOT NULL,
`status_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
`invite_prefix` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
`total_mark` float NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

### --
-- Dumping data for table `exam`

INSERT INTO `exam` (`exam_id`, `instructor_id`, `course_code`, `title`, `type_id`, `no_of_questions`, `status_id`, `invite_prefix`, `total_mark`) VALUES
(32, '171103026', 'CSC313', 'Quiz', 2, 1, 2, 'zmB1s', 150),
(34, '171103018', 'CSC313', 'Quiz II', 1, 1, 1, 'EnXAS', 0),
(36, '171103018', 'CSC305', 'Quiz IV', 2, 1, 1, 'JRvsa', 0),
(37, '171103026', 'GST301', 'Final Exam', 2, 3, 1, 'WmYyO', 0),
(38, '171103026', 'CSC307', 'Final', 1, 3, 1, '86xjM', 0),
(39, '171103018', 'CSC309', 'Finals', 1, 2, 1, 'TTetm', 70),
(40, '171103026', 'CSC307', 'Finals', 3, 2, 2, 'qecrv', 0),
(41, '171103026', 'CSC303', 'Finger Exercise', 2, 2, 1, '6bWkp', 30),
(42, '171103018', 'GST301', 'Finals', 1, 2, 1, 'JQxa4', 0),
(43, 'mubaraqwahab', 'CSC307', 'Midterm', 1, 2, 1, 've3MG', 0),
(44, '171103026', 'CSC307', 'Finals', 2, 1, 1, 'KznOI', 10),
(45, '171103026', 'CSC307', 'Midterm', 2, 1, 2, 'zXSue', 100),
(46, '171103026', 'CSC307', '', 2, 1, 1, 'caT11', 0),
(47, '171103026', 'CSC334', 'Quiz', 3, 1, 1, 'ZxURZ', 50),
(48, '171103018', 'CSC334', 'Quiz', 1, 2, 1, 'qT2f9', 50),
(49, '171103018', 'GST301', 'Quiz', 2, 1, 1, 'QnwCM', 30),
(50, '171103026', 'CSC303', 'Quiz', 2, 1, 1, '4aJhz', 10),
(51, '171103026', 'CSC307', 'Mid', 1, 1, 2, '5p8Ob', 10),
(52, '171103026', 'CSC313', 'Finale', 1, 1, 2, 'UxPPh', 25),
(53, '171103026', 'CSC305', 'Quiz', 1, 1, 2, 'CRYjp', 30),
(54, '171103018', 'CSC309', 'Quiz 2', 2, 1, 1, '3zVbj', 12),
(55, '171103026', 'CSC307', 'Theory', 3, 2, 2, 'mssZb', 30);

---

### --
-- Table structure for table `exam_assignment`

CREATE TABLE `exam_assignment` (
`exam_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`assignee_id` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
`total_score` float DEFAULT NULL,
`status_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

### --
-- Dumping data for table `exam_assignment`

INSERT INTO `exam_assignment` (`exam_id`, `assignee_id`, `total_score`, `status_id`) VALUES
(32, '171103007', NULL, 5),
(32, '171103010', 100, 6),
(32, '171103018', 98, 2),
(37, '171103007', NULL, 1),
(37, '171103018', NULL, 3),
(38, '171103007', NULL, 1),
(38, '171103010', NULL, 1),
(38, '171103018', NULL, 1),
(39, '171103010', NULL, 1),
(39, '171103026', 20, 6),
(40, '171103010', NULL, 1),
(40, '171103018', NULL, 1),
(41, '171103010', NULL, 1),
(41, '171103018', NULL, 3),
(42, '171103018', NULL, 6),
(42, '171103026', NULL, 6),
(43, 'mubaraqwahab', NULL, 4),
(44, '171103026', 10, 6),
(45, '171103018', NULL, 2),
(45, '171103023', NULL, 1),
(47, '171103026', 7, 6),
(48, '171103026', 30, 6),
(49, '171103026', NULL, 5),
(50, '171103018', NULL, 5),
(50, 'mubaraqwahab', NULL, 5),
(51, '171103018', NULL, 5),
(51, 'mubaraqwahab', NULL, 5),
(52, '171103018', NULL, 5),
(53, '171103018', 30, 6),
(53, '171103026', NULL, 2),
(53, 'mubaraqwahab', 0, 6),
(54, '171103026', 0, 6),
(55, '171103018', 22, 6),
(55, 'mubaraqwahab', 0, 6);

---

### --
-- Table structure for table `exam_status`

CREATE TABLE `exam_status` (
`status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`value` varchar(45) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

### --
-- Dumping data for table `exam_status`

INSERT INTO `exam_status` (`status_id`, `value`) VALUES
(2, 'Closed'),
(1, 'Open');

---

### --
-- Table structure for table `exam_type`

CREATE TABLE `exam_type` (
`type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`value` varchar(45) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

### --
-- Dumping data for table `exam_type`

INSERT INTO `exam_type` (`type_id`, `value`) VALUES
(2, 'Fill in the blank'),
(1, 'Multi-choice'),
(3, 'Theory');

---

### --
-- Table structure for table `fill_in_question`

CREATE TABLE `fill_in_question` (
`exam_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`question_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
`question` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
`mark` float NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

### --
-- Dumping data for table `fill_in_question`

INSERT INTO `fill_in_question` (`exam_id`, `question_no`, `question`, `mark`) VALUES
(32, 1, 'PHP stands for ___', 15),
(36, 1, 'What's SSTF? ___', 100),
(37, 1, 'What lies at the nexus of talent, passion, need and conscience is ***?', 20),
(37, 2, '*** is value creation', 30),
(37, 3, 'BryCoal is an enterprise created by ___ (number) students', 50),
(41, 1, 'Java uses pointers, true or false? ___', 10),
(41, 2, 'JVM stands for ___', 20),
(44, 1, 'PCIe stands for ___', 10),
(45, 1, 'What's Architecture?', 100),
(49, 1, 'What lies at the nexus of TAPANECO is ___', 30),
(50, 1, 'Do you like Java? Yes/No? ***', 10),
(54, 1, 'What?***', 12);

---

### --
-- Table structure for table `fill_in_response`

CREATE TABLE `fill_in_response` (
`exam_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`question_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
`assignee_id` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
`response` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`score` float DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

### --
-- Dumping data for table `fill_in_response`

INSERT INTO `fill_in_response` (`exam_id`, `question_no`, `assignee_id`, `response`, `score`) VALUES
(32, 1, '171103018', 'Personal Home Page', 7.5),
(41, 1, '171103018', 'false', NULL),
(41, 2, '171103018', 'Java Virtual Machine', NULL),
(44, 1, '171103026', 'Peripheral Component Interconnect Express', 10),
(49, 1, '171103026', 'entrepreneurial voice', NULL),
(54, 1, '171103026', 'efsdsds', 0.1);

---

### --
-- Table structure for table `level`

CREATE TABLE `level` (
`level_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`value` varchar(45) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

### --
-- Dumping data for table `level`

INSERT INTO `level` (`level_id`, `value`) VALUES
(1, '100'),
(2, '200'),
(3, '300'),
(4, '400'),
(5, '500');

---

### --
-- Table structure for table `multi_choice_question`

CREATE TABLE `multi_choice_question` (
`exam_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`question_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
`question` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
`correct_answer` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
`a` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
`b` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
`c` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
`d` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
`mark` float NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

### --
-- Dumping data for table `multi_choice_question`

INSERT INTO `multi_choice_question` (`exam_id`, `question_no`, `question`, `correct_answer`, `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `mark`) VALUES
(34, 1, 'What's HTML?', 'B', 'Hypertext's markdown language', 'Hypertext markup language', 'Hyperthreaded machine link', 'Hyperthreaded motor link', 10),
(38, 3, 'What was the last thing we did in class?', 'A', 'Presentation', 'Revision', 'Normal class', 'Lab class', 35),
(39, 1, 'abcdefghiljkad sdjasj asd', 'A', 'assdjsk', 'fdkjfdf', 'Cascading Style Sheets', 'ajkd', 20),
(39, 2, 'fdfh sjdk rekj aslkjf dnxv', 'D', 'qwere', 'dfvcx', 'asdfd', 'ythgb', 50),
(42, 1, 'What lies at the nexus of TAPANECO?', 'C', 'Talent', 'Passion', 'Voice', 'Conscience', 2),
(42, 2, 'Why did you choose what you chose above?', 'A', 'I felt like', 'I felt it is the correct answer', 'None of the above', 'All of the above', 1),
(43, 1, 'abc def', 'C', 'abc', 'cef', 'ghi', 'ajkd', 4),
(43, 2, 'adfghjy yutfd', 'A', 'hgf', 'dfgh', 'uyg', 'cvb', 6),
(48, 1, 'Which of these did'nt we do in class?', 'C', 'Simpson's Rule', 'Newton-Raphson', 'Taylor expansion', 'Bisection method', 20),
(48, 2, 'What's the name of your lecturer?', 'B', 'Prof. Agwu', 'Dr. Mary', 'Prof. Moussa', 'Mr. Salisu', 30),
(51, 1, 'Who's the lecturer', 'A', 'Mr Salisu', 'Mr Saka', 'Mr Dalhatu', 'Mr Abass', 10),
(52, 1, 'Which isn't related to Web?', 'D', 'PHP', 'HTML', 'jQuery', 'OralB', 25),
(53, 1, 'Paging and not what?', 'C', 'Virtual memory', 'Segmentation', 'Bootstrap', 'Memory allocation', 30);

---

### --
-- Table structure for table `multi_choice_response`

CREATE TABLE `multi_choice_response` (
`exam_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`question_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
`assignee_id` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
`response` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`score` float DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

### --
-- Dumping data for table `multi_choice_response`

INSERT INTO `multi_choice_response` (`exam_id`, `question_no`, `assignee_id`, `response`, `score`) VALUES
(39, 1, '171103026', 'a', 20),
(39, 2, '171103026', 'c', 0),
(42, 1, '171103018', 'C', 2),
(42, 1, '171103026', 'D', 0),
(42, 2, '171103018', 'A', 1),
(42, 2, '171103026', 'A', 1),
(43, 1, 'mubaraqwahab', 'A', 0),
(43, 2, 'mubaraqwahab', 'A', 6),
(48, 1, '171103026', 'D', 0),
(48, 2, '171103026', 'B', 30),
(53, 1, '171103018', 'C', 30),
(53, 1, 'mubaraqwahab', 'D', 0);

---

### --
-- Table structure for table `notification`

CREATE TABLE `notification` (
`notification_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`recipient_id` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
`status_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
`type_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`sender_id` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
`exam_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`time_stamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

### --
-- Dumping data for table `notification`

INSERT INTO `notification` (`notification_id`, `recipient_id`, `status_id`, `type_id`, `sender_id`, `exam_id`, `time_stamp`) VALUES
(19, '171103018', 2, 2, '171103026', 47, '2020-01-05 00:39:59'),
(20, '171103018', 2, 3, '171103026', 41, '2020-01-05 00:48:14'),
(21, '171103018', 2, 4, '171103026', 46, '2020-01-05 00:48:14'),
(22, '171103018', 2, 5, '171103026', 45, '2020-01-05 00:49:57'),
(23, '171103018', 2, 6, '171103026', 40, '2020-01-05 00:49:57'),
(24, '171103018', 2, 7, '171103026', 44, '2020-01-05 00:51:23'),
(25, '171103018', 2, 8, '171103026', 47, '2020-01-05 00:51:23'),
(26, '171103010', 1, 8, '171103026', 46, '2020-01-05 02:24:55'),
(31, '171103026', 2, 2, '171103018', 45, '2020-01-05 10:33:33'),
(36, '171103026', 2, 3, '171103018', 45, '2020-01-05 11:03:49'),
(38, '171103026', 2, 3, '171103018', 45, '2020-01-05 11:10:00'),
(40, '171103026', 2, 2, '171103018', 45, '2020-01-05 11:12:59'),
(42, '171103026', 2, 2, '171103018', 45, '2020-01-05 11:16:57'),
(44, '171103026', 2, 3, '171103018', 45, '2020-01-05 11:20:18'),
(46, '171103026', 2, 3, '171103018', 45, '2020-01-05 11:23:33'),
(48, '171103018', 2, 2, '171103026', 48, '2020-01-05 11:31:28'),
(49, '171103018', 2, 6, '171103026', 48, '2020-01-05 11:55:38'),
(50, '171103026', 2, 7, '171103018', 48, '2020-01-05 11:55:38'),
(51, '171103018', 2, 4, '171103026', 49, '2020-01-05 12:35:29'),
(52, '171103018', 2, 2, '171103026', 49, '2020-01-05 12:43:24'),
(53, '171103018', 2, 6, '171103026', 49, '2020-01-05 12:43:40'),
(55, '171103026', 2, 2, '171103018', 50, '2020-01-05 13:15:33'),
(56, '171103026', 2, 4, 'mubaraqwahab', 50, '2020-01-05 13:16:38'),
(57, '171103026', 2, 5, '171103018', 50, '2020-01-05 13:17:04'),
(58, '171103026', 2, 5, 'mubaraqwahab', 50, '2020-01-05 13:20:26'),
(60, '171103026', 2, 4, 'mubaraqwahab', 51, '2020-01-05 13:30:27'),
(61, '171103026', 2, 2, '171103018', 51, '2020-01-05 13:31:21'),
(62, '171103026', 2, 5, '171103018', 51, '2020-01-05 13:31:27'),
(63, '171103026', 2, 5, 'mubaraqwahab', 51, '2020-01-05 13:33:01'),
(65, '171103026', 2, 2, '171103018', 52, '2020-01-05 13:43:20'),
(66, '171103026', 2, 5, '171103018', 52, '2020-01-05 13:47:31'),
(69, '171103026', 2, 3, '171103026', 53, '2020-01-05 13:56:06'),
(70, '171103026', 2, 2, '171103018', 53, '2020-01-05 13:56:25'),
(71, '171103026', 2, 5, '171103018', 53, '2020-01-05 13:56:36'),
(72, '171103026', 2, 6, '171103018', 53, '2020-01-05 13:56:40'),
(73, '171103018', 2, 7, '171103026', 53, '2020-01-05 13:56:40'),
(74, '171103026', 2, 4, 'mubaraqwahab', 53, '2020-01-05 13:57:16'),
(75, '171103026', 2, 5, 'mubaraqwahab', 53, '2020-01-05 13:58:04'),
(76, '171103026', 2, 6, 'mubaraqwahab', 53, '2020-01-05 13:58:35'),
(77, 'mubaraqwahab', 2, 7, '171103026', 53, '2020-01-05 13:58:35'),
(78, '171103018', 2, 4, '171103026', 54, '2020-01-05 15:18:39'),
(79, '171103018', 2, 5, '171103026', 54, '2020-01-05 15:18:47'),
(80, '171103018', 2, 6, '171103026', 54, '2020-01-05 15:19:06'),
(81, '171103026', 2, 5, '171103026', 44, '2020-01-05 15:24:00'),
(82, '171103026', 2, 6, '171103026', 44, '2020-01-05 15:24:05'),
(84, '171103026', 2, 2, '171103018', 55, '2020-01-05 15:56:53'),
(85, '171103026', 2, 4, 'mubaraqwahab', 55, '2020-01-05 15:57:08'),
(86, '171103026', 2, 5, '171103018', 55, '2020-01-05 15:57:31'),
(87, '171103026', 2, 6, '171103018', 55, '2020-01-05 15:57:58'),
(88, '171103026', 2, 5, 'mubaraqwahab', 55, '2020-01-05 15:58:04'),
(89, '171103026', 2, 6, 'mubaraqwahab', 55, '2020-01-05 15:58:24'),
(90, 'mubaraqwahab', 2, 7, '171103026', 55, '2020-01-05 16:14:16'),
(91, '171103018', 2, 8, '171103026', 55, '2020-01-05 16:36:05'),
(92, 'mubaraqwahab', 2, 8, '171103026', 55, '2020-01-05 16:36:05'),
(93, '171103018', 2, 8, '171103026', 55, '2020-01-05 16:36:25'),
(94, 'mubaraqwahab', 2, 8, '171103026', 55, '2020-01-05 16:36:25'),
(95, '171103018', 2, 8, '171103026', 55, '2020-01-05 16:41:54'),
(96, 'mubaraqwahab', 1, 8, '171103026', 55, '2020-01-05 16:41:54'),
(97, '171103018', 2, 8, '171103026', 55, '2020-01-05 16:42:06'),
(98, 'mubaraqwahab', 1, 8, '171103026', 55, '2020-01-05 16:42:07'),
(99, '171103018', 2, 8, '171103026', 55, '2020-01-05 16:42:08'),
(100, 'mubaraqwahab', 1, 8, '171103026', 55, '2020-01-05 16:42:08'),
(101, '171103018', 2, 8, '171103026', 55, '2020-01-05 16:43:09'),
(102, 'mubaraqwahab', 1, 8, '171103026', 55, '2020-01-05 16:43:10');

---

### --
-- Table structure for table `notification_status`

CREATE TABLE `notification_status` (
`status_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`value` varchar(45) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

### --
-- Dumping data for table `notification_status`

INSERT INTO `notification_status` (`status_id`, `value`) VALUES
(1, 'Unviewed'),
(2, 'Viewed');

---

### --
-- Table structure for table `notification_type`

CREATE TABLE `notification_type` (
`type_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`value` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`msg_template` varchar(64) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

### --
-- Dumping data for table `notification_type`

INSERT INTO `notification_type` (`type_id`, `value`, `msg_template`) VALUES
(1, 'Invite', '[User] has invited you to take [Exam]'),
(2, 'Accepted invite', '[User] has accepted your invite to take [Exam]'),
(3, 'Declined invite', '[User] has declined your invite to take [Exam]'),
(4, 'Joined by code', '[User] has joined [Exam] by invite code'),
(5, 'Started exam', '[User] has started [Exam]'),
(6, 'Completed exam', '[User] has completed [Exam]'),
(7, 'Graded exam', '[User] has graded [Exam]'),
(8, 'Closed exam', '[User] has closed [Exam]');

---

### --
-- Table structure for table `theory_question`

CREATE TABLE `theory_question` (
`exam_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`question_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
`question` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
`mark` float NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

### --
-- Dumping data for table `theory_question`

INSERT INTO `theory_question` (`exam_id`, `question_no`, `question`, `mark`) VALUES
(40, 1, 'What is your name?', 20),
(40, 2, 'What is my surname?', 30),
(47, 1, 'What is numerical analysis?', 50),
(55, 1, 'What is structure?', 15),
(55, 2, 'What is function?', 15);

---

### --
-- Table structure for table `theory_response`

CREATE TABLE `theory_response` (
`exam_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`question_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
`assignee_id` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
`response` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
`score` float DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

### --
-- Dumping data for table `theory_response`

INSERT INTO `theory_response` (`exam_id`, `question_no`, `assignee_id`, `response`, `score`) VALUES
(47, 1, '171103026', 'A mathematical course', 7),
(55, 1, '171103018', 'organization and interconnection of pc components', 10),
(55, 1, 'mubaraqwahab', 'Struct', 0),
(55, 2, '171103018', 'what the components do as part of structure', 12),
(55, 2, 'mubaraqwahab', 'A user defined function', 0);

---

### --
-- Table structure for table `user`

CREATE TABLE `user` (
`user_id` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
`first_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`last_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`level_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`profile_picture` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`recovery_key` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

### --
-- Dumping data for table `user`

INSERT INTO `user` (`user_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `password`, `level_id`, `profile_picture`, `recovery_key`) VALUES
('171103007', 'Isa', 'Elleman', 'isaelleman@gmail.com', 'IsahE123', 3, NULL, NULL),
('171103010', 'Isiaq', 'Ibrahim', 'isiaq@yahoo.com', 'qwerty123', 3, NULL, NULL),
('171103018', 'Mustapha', 'Ibrahim', 'mikabu38@gmail.com', 'f4b37afc59e0792a3ea73192c96eb554', 3, '6bb000002217edf20324947d1d8eb5b1.jpg', NULL),
('171103023', 'Ibrahim', 'Subair', 'isubair538@gmail.com', '7d15f9c41f7a78cca8c3e177a1fd8157', 3, '7f34abc2948b89c689b335391a17d20e.jpg', NULL),
('171103026', 'Mubaraq', 'Wahab', 'mub.wahab26@gmail.com', '433484b5317340f5c28e085bfffc78be', 3, 'dcba3346dff99f519e98f886b5f0b95c.jpg', NULL),
('muazumd', 'Muazu', 'Abubakar', 'muazumd@gmail.com', '9614fe5793fddfe3217c3501fefeb3ba', NULL, 'c8e8851d0bd8e4f4097bd26f0005379a.jpg', NULL),
('mubaraqwahab', 'Mubaraq', 'Wahab', 'mub.wahab26@yahoo.com', '1234567890', 3, 'df3ebd0416d9ca00d1497f1a86344729.jpg', '770864');

### --
-- Indexes for dumped tables

### --
-- Indexes for table `assignment_status`

ALTER TABLE `assignment_status`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`status_id`),
ADD UNIQUE KEY `assignment_status_value_UNIQUE` (`value`);

### --
-- Indexes for table `course`

ALTER TABLE `course`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`course_code`),
ADD UNIQUE KEY `course_name_UNIQUE` (`course_name`);

### --
-- Indexes for table `exam`

ALTER TABLE `exam`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`exam_id`),
ADD KEY `exam_course_code_idx` (`course_code`),
ADD KEY `exam_type_id_idx` (`type_id`),
ADD KEY `exam_instructor_id_idx` (`instructor_id`),
ADD KEY `exam_status_id` (`status_id`);

### --
-- Indexes for table `exam_assignment`

ALTER TABLE `exam_assignment`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`exam_id`,`assignee_id`),
ADD KEY `assignment_assignee_id_idx` (`assignee_id`),
ADD KEY `assignment_status_id_idx` (`status_id`);

### --
-- Indexes for table `exam_status`

ALTER TABLE `exam_status`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`status_id`),
ADD UNIQUE KEY `exam_status_value_UNIQUE` (`value`);

### --
-- Indexes for table `exam_type`

ALTER TABLE `exam_type`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`type_id`),
ADD UNIQUE KEY `exam_type_value_UNIQUE` (`value`);

### --
-- Indexes for table `fill_in_question`

ALTER TABLE `fill_in_question`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`exam_id`,`question_no`);

### --
-- Indexes for table `fill_in_response`

ALTER TABLE `fill_in_response`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`exam_id`,`question_no`,`assignee_id`),
ADD KEY `fill_in_response_assignee_id_idx` (`assignee_id`);

### --
-- Indexes for table `level`

ALTER TABLE `level`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`level_id`),
ADD UNIQUE KEY `level_value_UNIQUE` (`value`);

### --
-- Indexes for table `multi_choice_question`

ALTER TABLE `multi_choice_question`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`exam_id`,`question_no`);

### --
-- Indexes for table `multi_choice_response`

ALTER TABLE `multi_choice_response`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`exam_id`,`question_no`,`assignee_id`),
ADD KEY `multi_choice_response_assignee_id_idx` (`assignee_id`);

### --
-- Indexes for table `notification`

ALTER TABLE `notification`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`notification_id`),
ADD KEY `notification_status_id` (`status_id`),
ADD KEY `notification_sender_id` (`sender_id`),
ADD KEY `notification_type_id` (`type_id`),
ADD KEY `notification_recipient_id` (`recipient_id`),
ADD KEY `exam_id` (`exam_id`);

-

Comment: You didn't post the structure of the student_response table, but based on the user table it looks like it should be "user_id" and not "userID". It also looks like it should be "exam_id" and not "examID".